# If $a_{n_m} \to 0$ and also $a_{n_m + r} \to 0$ for all $r > 1$, can we conclude that $a_n \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

There is a question in calculus:
Assume that $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is a positive sequence and $\{n_m\}_{m\ge 1}$ is a subsequence of $\{n\}$.

If the following limits hold:
$$a_{n_m}\to 0\quad\quad m\to\infty$$
$$\forall r>1,\quad a_{n_m+r}\to 0\quad m\to\infty,$$

is $$a_n\to 0\quad n\to\infty$$holds?

It intuitively appears that's right,but I do not know how to prove it.

Could anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Consider rewording the title, this question is not in any way "fundamental" in the field of calculus.

Comment: Have you tried finding a counterexample?

Comment: Yeah,I tried to find some counterexamples but unfortunately I didnot make it.

Comment: So what happened when you tried finding a counterexample? What did you try?

Comment: Try something like this maybe.  If $n=2^k +r$ where $r=0,1,2,3,\dots, 2^k-1$ write $a_n= \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{r}{2^k}$.  Then $a_{2^k} \to 0$ but perhaps ...

Comment: I tried to construct a sequence by assigning different numbers according to the reminder of the subindex divided by 2,3,4,5....  But it did not give me what I expected.

Comment: OK, I got it,that's right. Thanks for your kind answer.@B.S.Thomson